# How to change the Text of a IWebElement of Selenium in C#

Tags: selenium2, c#

The Title pretty much explains everything. I'm searching for a way to change let's say

```
<h1 id="title">Title<h1>
```

to

```
<h1 id="title">Nothing<h1>
```

I'm kind of desperate since

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("title")).Text;
```

doesn't allow assignment.

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do? I'm very curious. You don't normally use Webdriver to change the elements on a page; it's for interacting with it the way a human would, and humans don't usually edit the HTML directly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quickly glanced over the properties and methods of IWebElement, doesn't look like they can set values.
However, you can easily execute some javascript snippet to change HTML in your page.

```
IWebDriver driver;
IJavaScriptExecutor js = driver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
js.ExecuteScript("document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "New text!";");
```

*You might need to escape the inner quotation marks, haven't been able to run an actual test. Or use single apostrophes.*

Comment: you should not even need to create a `IJavaScriptExecutor` you can just do `driver.ExecuteScript()`

Answer (score 0):

I did this on Selenium Vba and it worked fine:

```
attrScript00 = "document.getElementById('title').innerText = 'New text2!'"
driver.ExecuteScript attrScript00

attrScript00 = "document.getElementById('title').innerHTML = 'New text3!'"
driver.ExecuteScript attrScript00
```